# how can i query one to many relationship query aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, schema, aws-amplify

how can i make this query in the screenshot from the client side.
[image: this is the query i want to perform.]

this is how i tried to do the query, but i don't know what to do next

```
const CategoriesProducts = async ()=>{
const fetchData = await API.graphql({
    query: listProductCategories, variables: {id: '1cb76030-0ee0-432a-b3ee-4087d33eaaf3'}
})
setCategoryProduct(fetchData.data.listProductCategories.items)}
```

this is my schema

[image]

and this is the getProductCategories queries

[image]

and this is the listProductCategories queries

[image]

i get the result when i make the query in te aws console, but i can't perform the same query in visual studio code

thank you for your support

Answer (score 0):

In your graphql directory auto-generated by aws-cli, create new file, `custom-queries.js` :

```
- graphql/
  - mutations.js
  - subscriptions.js
  - queries.js
  - custom-queries.js << Create this new file
```

define the following custom graphql query inside `custom-queries.js` :

```
 export const ListProductCategoriesByCategoryId = /* Graphql */ `
    query listProductCategories(
      $filter = ModelProductCategoryFilterInput
       ){
         listProductCategories( filter : $filter) {
           items {
              product {
                        price
                        image
                        id
                        title
                      }
                }
          }
        }
    `;
```

Now you should be able to import `ListProductCategoriesByCategoryId` in your code and call it like this :

```
   import { API, graphqlOperation } from 'aws-amplify';
   import { ListProductCategoriesByCategoryId } from '../custom-queries.js';
.
.
.
   const fetchData = await API.graphql(
    graphqlOperation(
     ListProductCategoriesByCategoryId, 
           { filter : { categoryID : { eq : "1cb76....." }}
     )
   );
   console.log(fetchData);
```

Comment: Hi Rohan i tried your code but i got this error 
` [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Body must be a string. Received: undefined.]
at node_modules\graphql\jsutils\devAssert.js:12:10 in devAssert
at node_modules\graphql\language\source.js:37:32 in Source
at node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:86:61 in Parser
at node_modules\graphql\language\parser.js:30:15 in parse
at node_modules\@aws-amplify\api-graphql\lib-esm\GraphQLAPI.js:278:14 in GraphQLAPIClass.prototype.graphql
at node_modules\@aws-amplify\api\lib-esm\API.js:207:15 in APIClass.prototype.graphql
at src\screens\Home.js`